# SOAP Header with identity of final client

Tags: wcf, soap, header

The environment is in-house service based applications running in a Windows environment with WCF.

- There are several "middle-tier" ASP.NET Web Applications and Web Services that authenticate the final client using Windows authentication, and use ASP.NET Roles to set Thread.CurrentPrincipal to a suitable RolePrincipal.  These applications each run under their own service account, which is a domain account, and are considered to be trusted subsystems.
- Some back-end WCF web services that may only be accessed by these trusted "middle-tier" applications.  They use Windows Authentication to limit access to the service accounts used by these applications.

We now have a requirement for the back-end services to audit the identity of the final client whose call to the middle-tier application resulted in the call to the back-end service.

To avoid making any application changes, I was thinking of writing an endpoint behavior which inserts a SOAP Header with the final client's identity into the request sent to the back-end service.  Note that the middle-tier applications are trusted, so no authentication of this SOAP Header would be required.

It occurred to me that this requirement may not be unique, so before I invent my own SOAP Header for this purpose I thought I'd ask if there exist any standards in this area I could reuse?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after WCF Impersonation, check out the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx) or Google that search term for more info. I've never used it myself so can't fully advise, but hopefully it's what you're after. Good luck

Edit: Does the WCF OperationContext not carry through the identity to the second phase? (OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name)

Comment: No I'm not after impersonation.  The middle-tier app is a trusted subsystem that runs under its own identity: I don't want it to impersonate its client - just to transfer some information about the client in a SOAP Header.  I can easily do this myself with a custom SOAP Header, but wondered if there was a standard.

Comment: Apologies, not sure about any standards, although I've been down the custom soap header route myself so if you have any queries with that let me know.